# misbehaving colors in rclock

Tags: colors, clock, xorg

For many years I experience a puzzling problem with rclock. I use rclock on many different Slackware boxes which all feature the same slack version. rclock helps to keep ssh connections open. As my X and fvwm have a dark screen background I prefer rclock (or xlcock) to run with :

```
rclock -update 1 -bg black -fg blue
```

Now it happens that either at rclock start time or 'automagically' any time later the background and foreground color settings switch apparently for no reason so that rclock subsequently turns into a bright blue patch - which then annoyingly mimics my xbiff's mail arrival announcement. The only somewhat silly solution i have for now is to manually switch -fg and -bg each time when restarting a misbehaving rclock.

Any idea what causes this ?

Comment: as this is not really a problem with code you wrote, i would rather ask that on the rclock mailing-list or bug-tracker or whatever they use

Comment: yes, you are right - i am sorry about this.  i am still a novice here.